# How to connect from node js to mongodb replica set using SSL

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ssl

I am trying to connect to a mongodb replica set which is set up to authenticate clients using SSL. I can connect using the mongo shell, but for some reason cannot connect from node.js with the same keys.
I am using mongodb version 3.2.6 and node.js driver version 2.1.18, running on mac.

I followed [this article](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/secure-mongodb-with-x-509-authentication), and was able to setup a cluster on my local machine by running the attached script:

```
# Prerequisites:
#   a. Make sure you have MongoDB Enterprise installed. 
#   b. Make sure mongod/mongo are in the executable path
#   c. Make sure no mongod running on 27017 port, or change the port below
#   d. Run this script in a clean directory

##### Feel free to change following section values ####
# Changing this to include: country, province, city, company
dn_prefix="/C=CN/ST=GD/L=Shenzhen/O=MongoDB China"
ou_member="MyServers"
ou_client="MyClients"
mongodb_server_hosts=( "server1" "server2" "server3" )
mongodb_client_hosts=( "client1" "client2" )
mongodb_port=27017


# make a subdirectory for mongodb cluster
kill $(ps -ef | grep mongod | grep set509 | awk '{print $2}')
#rm -Rf db/*
mkdir -p db

echo "##### STEP 1: Generate root CA "
openssl genrsa -out root-ca.key 2048
# !!! In production you will want to use -aes256 to password protect the keys
# openssl genrsa -aes256 -out root-ca.key 2048

openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -key root-ca.key -out root-ca.crt -subj "$dn_prefix/CN=ROOTCA"

mkdir -p RootCA/ca.db.certs
echo "01" >> RootCA/ca.db.serial
touch RootCA/ca.db.index
echo $RANDOM >> RootCA/ca.db.rand
mv root-ca* RootCA/

echo "##### STEP 2: Create CA config"
# Generate CA config
cat >> root-ca.cfg <<EOF
[ RootCA ]
dir             = ./RootCA
certs           = \$dir/ca.db.certs
database        = \$dir/ca.db.index
new_certs_dir   = \$dir/ca.db.certs
certificate     = \$dir/root-ca.crt
serial          = \$dir/ca.db.serial
private_key     = \$dir/root-ca.key
RANDFILE        = \$dir/ca.db.rand
default_md      = sha256
default_days    = 365
default_crl_days= 30
email_in_dn     = no
unique_subject  = no
policy          = policy_match

[ SigningCA ]
dir             = ./SigningCA
certs           = \$dir/ca.db.certs
database        = \$dir/ca.db.index
new_certs_dir   = \$dir/ca.db.certs
certificate     = \$dir/signing-ca.crt
serial          = \$dir/ca.db.serial
private_key     = \$dir/signing-ca.key
RANDFILE        = \$dir/ca.db.rand
default_md      = sha256
default_days    = 365
default_crl_days= 30
email_in_dn     = no
unique_subject  = no
policy          = policy_match

[ policy_match ]
countryName     = match
stateOrProvinceName = match
localityName            = match
organizationName    = match
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName      = supplied
emailAddress        = optional

[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

[ v3_ca ]
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer:always
basicConstraints = CA:true
EOF

echo "##### STEP 3: Generate signing key"
# We do not use root key to sign certificate, instead we generate a signing key
openssl genrsa -out signing-ca.key 2048
# !!! In production you will want to use -aes256 to password protect the keys
# openssl genrsa -aes256 -out signing-ca.key 2048

openssl req -new -days 1460 -key signing-ca.key -out signing-ca.csr -subj "$dn_prefix/CN=CA-SIGNER"
openssl ca -batch -name RootCA -config root-ca.cfg -extensions v3_ca -out signing-ca.crt -infiles signing-ca.csr 

mkdir -p SigningCA/ca.db.certs
echo "01" >> SigningCA/ca.db.serial
touch SigningCA/ca.db.index
# Should use a better source of random here..
echo $RANDOM >> SigningCA/ca.db.rand
mv signing-ca* SigningCA/

# Create root-ca.pem
cat RootCA/root-ca.crt SigningCA/signing-ca.crt > root-ca.pem



echo "##### STEP 4: Create server certificates"
# Now create & sign keys for each mongod server 
# Pay attention to the OU part of the subject in "openssl req" command
# You may want to use FQDNs instead of short hostname
for host in "${mongodb_server_hosts[@]}"; do
    echo "Generating key for $host"
    openssl genrsa  -out ${host}.key 2048
    openssl req -new -days 365 -key ${host}.key -out ${host}.csr -subj "$dn_prefix/OU=$ou_member/CN=${host}"
    openssl ca -batch -name SigningCA -config root-ca.cfg -out ${host}.crt -infiles ${host}.csr
    cat ${host}.crt ${host}.key > ${host}.pem   
done 

echo "##### STEP 5: Create client certificates"
# Now create & sign keys for each client
# Pay attention to the OU part of the subject in "openssl req" command
for host in "${mongodb_client_hosts[@]}"; do
    echo "Generating key for $host"
    openssl genrsa  -out ${host}.key 2048
    openssl req -new -days 365 -key ${host}.key -out ${host}.csr -subj "$dn_prefix/OU=$ou_client/CN=${host}"
    openssl ca -batch -name SigningCA -config root-ca.cfg -out ${host}.crt -infiles ${host}.csr
    cat ${host}.crt ${host}.key > ${host}.pem
done 

echo ""
echo "##### STEP 6: Start up replicaset in non-auth mode"
mport=$mongodb_port
for host in "${mongodb_server_hosts[@]}"; do
    echo "Starting server $host in non-auth mode"   
    mkdir -p ./db/${host}
    mongod --replSet set509 --port $mport --dbpath ./db/$host \
        --fork --logpath ./db/${host}.log       
    let "mport++"
done 
sleep 3
# obtain the subject from the client key:
client_subject=`openssl x509 -in ${mongodb_client_hosts[0]}.pem -inform PEM -subject -nameopt RFC2253 | grep subject | awk '{sub("subject= ",""); print}'`

echo "##### STEP 7: setup replicaset & initial user role\n"
myhostname=`hostname`
cat > setup_auth.js <<EOF
rs.initiate();
mport=$mongodb_port;
mport++;
rs.add("$myhostname:" + mport);
mport++;
rs.add("$myhostname:" + mport);
sleep(5000);
db.getSiblingDB("\$external").runCommand(
    {
        createUser: "$client_subject",
        roles: [
             { role: "readWrite", db: 'test' },
             { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
             { role: "clusterAdmin", db:"admin"}
           ],
        writeConcern: { w: "majority" , wtimeout: 5000 }
    }
);
EOF
cat setup_auth.js
mongo localhost:$mongodb_port setup_auth.js 
kill $(ps -ef | grep mongod | grep set509 | awk '{print $2}')
sleep 3

echo "##### STEP 8: Restart replicaset in x.509 mode\n"
mport=$mongodb_port
for host in "${mongodb_server_hosts[@]}"; do
    echo "Starting server $host"    
    mongod --replSet set509 --port $mport --dbpath ./db/$host \
        --sslMode requireSSL --clusterAuthMode x509 --sslCAFile root-ca.pem \
        --sslAllowInvalidHostnames --fork --logpath ./db/${host}.log \
        --sslPEMKeyFile ${host}.pem --sslClusterFile ${host}.pem
    let "mport++"
done 


# echo "##### STEP 9: Connecting to replicaset using certificate\n"
cat > do_login.js <<EOF
db.getSiblingDB("\$external").auth(
  {
    mechanism: "MONGODB-X509",
    user: "$client_subject"
  }
)
EOF

# mongo --ssl --sslPEMKeyFile client1.pem --sslCAFile root-ca.pem --sslAllowInvalidHostnames --shell do_login.js
```

After running the cluster, I am able to connect to it using the mongo shell with this command (all keys\certs were generated in ./ssl dir):

```
mongo --ssl --sslPEMKeyFile ssl/client1.pem --sslCAFile ssl/root-ca.pem --sslAllowInvalidHostnames
```

and authenticate as follows:

```
db.getSiblingDB("$external").auth(
  {
    mechanism: "MONGODB-X509",
    user: "CN=client1,OU=MyClients,O=MongoDB China,L=Shenzhen,ST=GD,C=CN"
  }
)
```

When I try to connect from node.js I keep failing. I am running the following code to connect to mongo using the native mongo driver:

```
'use strict';

const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const P = require('bluebird');
const fs = require('fs');

function connect_mongodb() {
    let user = 'CN=client1,OU=MyClients,O=MongoDB China,L=Shenzhen,ST=GD,C=CN';
    let uri = `mongodb://${encodeURIComponent(user)}@localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019/test?replicaSet=set509&authMechanism=MONGODB-X509&ssl=true`;
    var ca = [fs.readFileSync("./ssl/root-ca.pem")];
    var cert = fs.readFileSync("./ssl/client1.pem");
    var key = fs.readFileSync("./ssl/client1.pem");
    let options = {
        promiseLibrary: P,
        server: {
            ssl: true,
            sslValidate: false,
            checkServerIdentity: false,
            sslCA: ca,
            sslKey: key,
            sslCert: cert,
        },
        replset: {
            sslValidate: false,
            checkServerIdentity: false,
            ssl: true,
            sslCA: ca,
            sslKey: key,
            sslCert: cert,
        }
    };
    return mongodb.MongoClient.connect(uri, options);
}

connect_mongodb();
```

When running the script I get the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection MongoError: no valid seed servers in list
```

When checking the mongodb log I see these errors:

```
2017-01-17T22:48:54.191+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:63881 #99 (5 connections now open)
2017-01-17T22:48:54.207+0200 E NETWORK  [conn99] no SSL certificate provided by peer; connection rejected
2017-01-17T22:48:54.207+0200 I NETWORK  [conn99] end connection 127.0.0.1:63881 (4 connections now open)
```

I was trying different options [described here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/tutorials/connect/ssl/), but with no success.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to mongodb node js driver 2.2.22 solved the problem